# Is the hypergeometric function ${}_1F_2(1;a,a+\frac12;-x^2)$ an elementary function? How about its positivity, monotonicity, and convexity in $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Is the generalized hypergeometric function ${}_1F_2\bigl(1;a,a+\frac12;-x^2\bigr)$ for $a>-1$ and $x>0$ an elementary function?

How about the positivity, monotonicity, and convexity of the generalized hypergeometric function ${}_1F_2\bigl(1; a, a+\frac{1}{2}; -x^2\bigr)$ in $x>0$ for $a\ge-1$?

Comment: In the question, the variable $a$ and $x$ are real. When $a$ is a positive integer, I can derive elementary expressions for ${}_1F_2\bigl(1,a,a+\frac12;x\bigr)$. So, please consider the case that the variable $a$ is real.

Comment: My question can be restated as: Is the hypergeometric function ${}_1F_2\bigl(1;a,a+\frac12;x\bigr)$ for non-integer $a>2$ and real variable $x<0$ an elementary function?

Answer (score 1):

Take $a=1/4$.
Maple says
$$
{}_1F_2\left(1;\frac14,\frac34;-x^2\right) =
1-2\,\sqrt {x}\sqrt {\pi}\sin \left( 2\,x \right)\, {C}\!
 \left( 2\,{\frac {\sqrt {x}}{\sqrt {\pi}}} \right) +2\,\sqrt {x}
\sqrt {\pi}\cos \left( 2\,x \right)\, {S}\! \left( 2\,{\frac {
\sqrt {x}}{\sqrt {\pi}}} \right) 
$$
in terms of the [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) $S$ and $C$.
Now, $S$ and $C$ are not elementary.  So I guess this combination is also not elementary.

---

Simplified ...
$$
{}_1F_2\left(1;\frac14,\frac34;-x^2\right) =
1+2\sqrt {x}\int_{-x}^{0}\!{\frac {\sin \left( 2\,r \right) }{\sqrt 
{r+x}}}\,{\rm d}r,\qquad x>0.
$$
The proof that $S$ is not elementary may also work for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question posed two very hard problems.

1. Are $a$ and $x$ reals as suggested.
2. Is $a$ hard to be interpreted as continuous.

If $a$ is continuous, the generalized hypergeometric stays not simplified and an interpretation with respect to elementary function is not possible.

From the use of indices, You gave two groups of values:

$\{1\}$ for the first lower index $1$

and

$\{a,a+\frac{1}{2}\}$ for the second lower index $2$ behind the symbol $F$.

I need a workaround to the condition $x<0$. For this is use $-abs(x)$.

So if I calculate

$_1F_2(\{1\};\{a,a+\frac{1}{2}\};-abs(x))$

for $a=2$, I get

$\frac{3\left(2\sqrt{|x|}-\sin\left(2\sqrt{|x|}\right)\right)}{4|x|^{3/2}}$

This is a composition of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). But it is certainly not an elementary function. For noninteger $a$ no such closed form is given.

For $a=3$, I get

$\frac{5\left(4|x|^{3/2}-6\sqrt{|x|}+3\sin\left(2\sqrt{|x|}\right)\right)}{4|x|^{5/2}}$

For $a=4$, I get

$\frac{5\left(4|x|^{3/2}-6\sqrt{|x|}+3\sin\left(2\sqrt{|x|}\right)\right)}{4|x|^{5/2}}$.

So the trend is clear more and more $\frac{1}{2}$ potences appear in the polynomial. For real $a$ the solution are continuous in between the integer ones.

The negative definition range alters the $\sinh$ to the $\sin$ that is all.

For $a=1$ the simplification is $\frac{\sin\left(2\sqrt{|x|}\right)}{2\sqrt{|x|}}$. So this is more elementary than the sums. The composition is only the quotient of two elementary functions.

Comment: Your results for $a=3$ and $a=4$ are the same which is inconsistent with [this WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5B%7Ba%2C+HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B1%7D%2C+%7Ba%2C+a+%2B+1%2F2%7D%2C+-Abs%5Bx%5D%5D%7D%2C+%7Ba%2C+1%2C+5%7D%5D).

Comment: When a is a positive integer, I can derive explicit and elementary expressions for ${}_1F_2\bigl(1;a,a+\frac12;x\bigr)$. What I want is the result for the case that the variable $a$ is not an integer.

Comment: Isn't a composition of (finitely many) elementary functions an elementary function?

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful - an expression in terms of the incomplete Gamma function. The series
$$
{}_1F_2(1;a,a+\frac12;-x^2)=1-\frac{4x^2}{2a(2a+1)}+\frac{16x^4}{2a(2a+1)(2a+2)(2a+3)}-\frac{64x^6}{2a(2a+1)(2a+2)(2a+3)(2a+4)(2a+5)}+...
$$
can be written as
$$
\frac12\left(f(2ix)+f(-2ix)\right),
$$
where
$$
f(t)=1+\frac t{2a}+\frac{t^2}{2a(2a+1)}+\frac{t^3}{2a(2a+1)(2a+2)}+...=\frac{2a-1}{t^{2a-1}}e^t(\Gamma(2a-1)-\Gamma(2a-1,t))
$$